# Update sonar to 4.1.2 failed to upgrade DB

Tags: oracle10g, sonarqube

I'm upgrading from Sonar 3.4.1 to 4.1.2 using Oracle 10.2

I've updated all plugins according to the version they are supported in the target version.

After clicking Upgrade button in /setup page I got this error:

```
2014.07.08 19:15:06 INFO  [DbMigration]
2014.07.08 19:15:06 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddNetworkUseSubCharacteristic: migrating =============================                                                                                                                          ====
2014.07.08 19:15:06 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-00904: "DESCRIPTION": invalid identifier
: INSERT INTO characteristics (kee, name, rule_id, characteristic_order, enabled, parent_id, root_id, function_key,                                                                                                                           factor_value, factor_unit, offset_value, offset_unit, created_at, updated_at, quality_model_id, depth, description,                                                                                                                           id) VALUES('NETWORK_USE_EFFICIENCY', 'Network use', NULL, NULL, 1, 10347, 10347, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, TO_TI                                                                                                                          MESTAMP('2014-07-08 19:15:06:825000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-08 19:15:06:825000','YYYY-M                                                                                                                          M-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6'), NULL, NULL, NULL, ?)
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac                                                                                                                          t_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac                                                                                                                          t_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/oracle/adapter.rb:183:                                                                                                                          in `ora_insert'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac                                                                                                                          t/query_cache.rb:26:in `insert_with_query_dirty'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2967:in `create'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:53:in `create_                                                                                                                          with_timestamps'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:266:in `create                                                                                                                          _with_callbacks'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2933:in `create_or_                                                                                                                          update'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:250:in `create                                                                                                                          _or_update_with_callbacks'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2583:in `save'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1089:in `sav                                                                                                                          e_with_validation'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_with_d                                                                                                                          irty'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2225:in `send'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `wit                                                                                                                          h_transaction_returning_status'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac                                                                                                                          t/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `tra                                                                                                                          nsaction'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `wit                                                                                                                          h_transaction_returning_status'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `sav                                                                                                                          e_with_transactions'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rol                                                                                                                          lback_active_record_state!'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `sav                                                                                                                          e_with_transactions'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:727:in `create'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/db/migrate/466_add_network_use_sub_characteristic.rb:42:in `up'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2221:in `send'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrat                                                                                                                          e'
        jar:file:/opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.6.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/ben                                                                                                                          chmark.rb:293:in `measure'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrat                                                                                                                          e'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2225:in `send'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:365:in `migrat                                                                                                                          e'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:491:in `migrat                                                                                                                          e'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `ddl_tr                                                                                                                          ansaction'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:490:in `migrat                                                                                                                          e'
        org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in `migrat                                                                                                                          e'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrat                                                                                                                          e'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
        /opt/sonarqube-4.1.2/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:109:in `start_migration'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:228:in `call'
```

Not sure why this error related to invalid identifier came up.
Thanks in advance for your help.

CHARACTERISTICS table structure:

{
 Name                                      Null?    Type

---

ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 KEE                                                VARCHAR2(100)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(100)
 RULE_ID                                            NUMBER(38)
 CHARACTERISTIC_ORDER                               NUMBER(38)
 ENABLED                                            NUMBER(1)
 PARENT_ID                                          NUMBER(38)
 ROOT_ID                                            NUMBER(38)
 FUNCTION_KEY                                       VARCHAR2(100)
 FACTOR_VALUE                                       NUMBER(30,20)
 FACTOR_UNIT                                        VARCHAR2(100)
 OFFSET_VALUE                                       NUMBER(30,20)
 OFFSET_UNIT                                        VARCHAR2(100)
 CREATED_AT                                         TIMESTAMP(6)
 UPDATED_AT                                         TIMESTAMP(6)
}

Comment: What's the structure (columns) of your table CHARACTERISTICS please ?

Comment: Could you try to upgrade from 3.4.1 to 3.7.x then to 4.x ?

Comment: I will try and let you know.

Comment: Finally I figure it out what the problems was. Sonar FAQ says this:

Comment: in: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing in section Failed to start SonarQube with Oracle due to bad USERS table structure even though this applies for any table not only USERS table. The problem was that I had a schema cloned (expdp/impdp) from Sonar schema with the same objects and data, so when I launched the migration it failed. What I ultimately did was to drop the cloned schema and the upgrade could be done successfully.